# Big query: wildcard tables are not supported over tables with column level ddl

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a sharded table in big query with this [table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P90qC.png) (data comes from facebook GraphAPI)

now I'm trying to flatten data with a query:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT `1d_click` FROM unnest(action_values) WHERE action_type='video_view') AS video_view_value_1d_click,
FROM `test.FBADS_COUNTRY_202305*`
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Wildcard tables are not supported over tables with column level ddl. Please consider exclude column action_values.1d_click from query, or filter out table test.FBADS_COUNTRY_20230525 with _TABLE_SUFFIX.

I noticed that if I would run this query on a specific shard - it would work.
Also, if I run this query:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT value FROM unnest(action_values) WHERE action_type='video_view') AS video_view_value_1d_click,
FROM `test.FBADS_COUNTRY_202305*`
```

everything is okay and no error occurs.

Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with wildcard:

**Wildcard tables are not supported over tables with columns pending to be dropped. First table: my_table_name**

Recreating a table from the error message has solved the issue.